# Construction of 3 circles touching each other externally.

Tags: geometric-construction

The context is construction of three circles with different radii so that they touch each other externally using a graduated ruler and a compass.

I have done it by drawing a triangle where each side is the sum of the radii of distinct combination of two circles and then drawing the circles by taking the vertex as the centre of a circle.

My question is why does my method work and is this the standard method to do the construction in context because i could not find anything about it on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method works well.  If you draw the line segments between each pair of centers they are composed of two radii, which justifies your construction.

Comment: Is this the standard method?

Comment: I would say so, but don't really know as I don't teach the subject.  It is simple and easy to justify, so it should be.